# Decompress MiniLZO String with Python 2.7/python-lzo 1.11

Tags: python, sockets, compression, lzo

I am writing a Python 2.7 program which interacts with a 3rd party TCP/IP-based API by sending and receiving data packets through a socket connection.

The data packets consists of the following parts:

- A header, which is 10 bytes long, is inserted in front of the data;
- Body;
- A trailer must be appended to the end of the data.

The header includes information about the length of the data and the type of data. The entire data packet includes a header, the actual data, and a trailer.

The compression method is MiniLZO.

My problem is how to handle the data — specifically the body of the packet, which is compressed with MiniLZO.

For example, when I sent a request like this:

```
bytearray(b'\x01W\x00\x00\x000W\x00\x00\x00')
<TASK><MESSAGE Type="LogonReq" Session="" Reference="TP1" Product="2">
</MESSAGE></TASK>
bytearray(b'\x02')
```

The server replies:

```
HEADER: 10 Bytes 

'\x01\xb1\x00\x00\x001\xae\x00\x00\x00'

BODY:177 Bytes 

'\x002<TASKREPLY><MESSAGE Type="LogonReqReply" Session="DUH3PRdH" 
ReferencP\x05\x00\x18TP1" Product="2">\r\n<ANSWER Result="1" 
Time@\x01\x00\x1225146" Date="20171028" Mode="P" /></\xcc\x11\x0c>
</TASKREPLY>\r\n\x11\x00\x00'

TRAILER:1 Bytes 

 '\x02'
```

I installed the package `python-lzo` 1.11 and tried to decompress the body by:

```
>>> import lzo
>>> lzo.decompress(body)
```

But it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    lzo.decompress(body)
error: Header error - invalid compressed data
```

I have no idea how to resolve the problem. I tried to google it, but it seems there is little information available about Python/MiniLZO. I am not sure if I used the `lzo` package in the wrong way or the data was compressed improperly in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I found that I need to pass the length of the compressed string to the decompress function to make it work. It works like this:

```
lzo.decompress(body,False,176)
```